# How can I get the english node title printed on the translated nodes edit page.

Tags: forms, 7, i18n-l10n

Something along the lines of this

```
function THEME_AMENDS_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   global $language;
   $lang = $language->language;
   $translations = translation_node_get_translations($base_node->tnid);
   $translated_node = (isset($translations[$lang])?node_load($translations[$lang]->nid):$base_node);
}
```

I want on the backend of the translated node above the form the english node title to be printed for reference only.

So say we have a contact page, I want on the (spanish) node in the backend above the content edit form "Page Title: Contact" to be printed above where the field for the translated title of the spanish node would be in which the user would translate the title to "contacto".

*Basic layout below:*

**Page Title: Contact**

Node title field: [Contacto] <-- input box

Answer (score 0):

Soluton

```
if($form_id == 'content_page_node_form') {
    $nid = (isset($form['nid']['#value'])) ? $form['nid']['#value'] : false;
    if($nid) {
        $node = node_load($nid);

        if($node) {
            $lang = 'en';
            $translations = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
            $translated_node = (isset($translations[$lang])) ? node_load($translations[$lang]->nid) : $node;
            $translated_title = '<h3>English Translation: ' . $translated_node->title . '</h3>';
        }
    }

    $form['#prefix'] = (isset($translated_title) && $translated_node->title != $node->title) ? $translated_title : '';
}
```